# Pandas irow() automatically converts int to float

Tags: python, pandas

```
x = DataFrame([(1,2.0),(2,4.0)], columns=['a','b'])
x.dtypes
a      int64
b    float64
a = x.irow(0)
a
output:
a    1.0
b    2.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

why does pandas convert automatically to float? how can I keep the int columns as int without use astype/cast for each field after using irow?

Answer (score 2):

It returns a `Series` for that row so the `dtype` is promoted to `float` due to the presence of the `float` in col `b`

```
In [33]:
type(x.irow(0))

Out[33]:
pandas.core.series.Series
```

Also that method is deprecated you should be using `iloc`:

```
In [31]:
x.iloc[0]

Out[31]:
a    1.0
b    2.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

In practicality this is not a real issue as accessing a specific column of a row will preserve the `dtype`:

```
In [36]:
x['a'].iloc[0]

Out[36]:
1

In [37]:
type(x['a'].iloc[0])

Out[37]:
numpy.int64
```

Comment: why it is changed to float? I don't want the field to convert automatically.
I have 30 columns in my data frame, I don't want to cast each one to int

Comment: So what should the `dtype` be for the `Series` without `dtype` promotion then?

Answer (score 0):

You could use dtype=object for use each data own type like below

```
df = pd.read_excel(INPUT_FILE, index_col=0, dtype=object)
```